# Expected value of collisions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, hash-function

There are two definitions that are needed in the following problem:

A probability distribution $H$ over a hash function $h : U \rightarrow \{1, 2, \ldots, m\}$  is said to be *universal* if for all $x\neq y$, $\sup_{h\in H} P(h(x) = P(h(y)) \leq 1/m$

If $H$ is universal and is a uniform distribution over a set of functions $\{h_1, h_2, \ldots\}$, then it is called a *universal hash family*

---

(a) Suppose $H$ is a universal hash family over a set of functions $\{h_1, h_2, \ldots\}$ (there is some abuse of notation going on here -- we say $H$ to mean both the set and the uniform distribution over it) from $U$ to $\{1, 2, \ldots, m\}$ and let $S\subseteq U$ be a set of $m$ elements we want to hash (the number of elements being hashed is equal to the size of the hash table). Now further, suppose that $h$ is drawn uniformly at random from $H$. Show that the expected number of collisions is at most $(m - 1)/2$.

(b) Continuing from (a), now show that the probability that no bin in the table gets more than $2\sqrt{m} + 1$ elements is at least $3/4$ (Hint: Use the previous part and consider Markov Inequality).

---

I was wondering if someone can please assist me with this problem. The first result is sort of intuitive to me but not really sure about the second one.

Let $X$ be the number of collisions (random variable). Then how can we bound $E(X)$?

Comment: What is $U$?  What does it mean here: "$h$ is drawn uniformly at random from $H$"?  How do you draw something at random from a function?  Do you mean you draw an element $u\in U$ with uniform distribution (whatever $U$ is), and $h=H(u)$?

Comment: $U$ a universe of keys that are getting mapped to their values. It is just a really, really large set with many integers. $H$ itself maps uniformly from $U$ to $\{1, 2, \ldots, m\}$. So every element $u \in S$ gets mapped to some element in $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, m\}$ which is denoted by $h = H(u)$

Comment: I am confused here.  Is $H$ a random function?  I think the problem is very unclear at this point.  How does a function map uniformly?

Comment: What is random here? What is a collision in this problem?  Is $S$ a random subset of $U$?

Comment: @Batominovski I have corrected the problem

Comment: @joseph: This is what you want to say. Let $H$ be a collection of maps from a finite set $U$ to $[m]\equiv\{1,\ldots,m\}$. Then, $H$ is called a universal family if for all $x\neq y$, $$\sup_{h\in H}\mathbb{P}(h(x)=h(y))\leq1/m.$$

Comment: Thanks. You are right.